# Fetch mail with Thunderbird Portable Edition

Tags: thunderbird

I've been using Thunderbird to read Gmail for some time. A few months ago I decided to switch to the portable version from PortableApps.com.
*Now the portable version only reads mail I got after installing it.*
 I think this is because Gmail "sees" that a version of Thunderbird has already fetched the old mail, so it isn't sending it to the new portable edition.
**How can I read ALL my emails ever in Thunderbird portable edition?**

Comment: Did you enable 'PoP for all mail even mail that has already been downloaded' under gmail settings?

Comment: I noticed that you posted a thank you, confirming that the suggestion in NetworkKingPin's comment worked, which was deleted.  Closing the loop on your question is great, but answers are reserved for actual solutions, which is why just a thanks got deleted.  Consider posting the actual solution as an answer, which will be helpful to others with the same problem.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you created two user accounts.  In order to edit your own post, comment within your thread, or accept an answer. that must be done under the account originally used to create the post (for your protection).  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged if you want to combine them (you might need to register one of the accounts).  For reference, your original account is https://superuser.com/users/721521/mr-x and the one you used to post the answer was https://superuser.com/users/721559/mr-x.